# What are the benefits / downsides of a high uptime?

Tags: memory, reboot, vps, uptime

Today I noticed that `htop` added a bang after the uptime of my server, because my server's uptime is now greater than **100 days**.

I don't know if this is a warning, or a congratulation : **What are the benefits / disadvantages of a high uptime** ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For what I understand now :

High uptime is good because :

- It means no service interruption (server restart is not instant)
- It means your server has no memory leakage and you do not need someone to monitor it closely (although it is a good practice to monitor it anyway, for example for updates and security)

Frequent restarts can be good because :

- It allows to deal with memory leakage
- It allows to deal with zombie / unkilled threads
- It allow to flush temporary folders, RAM, running process
- It will restart services that may have crashed with no automatic restart

Did I forget something ?

With this, I should take the exclamation mark (!) of `htop` as a "Congratulation, your server is stable over time" :)

Comment: For fun: https://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/103.html (uptime contest)

Comment: *Planned* reboots can be good - You may need to reboot for kernel updates